# How to split a string by length using split function and a RegEx in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split a string that represent a sequence of bits (only "0" and "1") in different strings with a length of 8.

I would like to use the javascript **split** function, and I know that It is possible to use a **regex** to achieve that division. I have something close to a solution:

```
"10111001110001011011".split(/([01]{8})/)
```

But it return an array with five elements, where there are two empty:

```
(5) ["", "10111001", "", "11000101", "1011"]
```

What should be the right regex to use in split to get one array with only the non empty strings. (I don´t want to use another function to filter the result...)

Comment: I don't think `.split` can do this. Try `.match` instead.

Comment: ok with match function! tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alexander pointed out at his comment, you need to use .match, like this:

```js
var binaryNumber = "1011100111000101101100110101110111011100010101";

console.log(binaryNumber.match(/.{1,8}/g));
```